# Semantic UI installed with PhantomJS using NPM 3+

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-ui

I have inherited a project, and am currently updating its node/npm version.  I just downloaded and started up node v5.1.0 which comes with npm v3.3.12.  Now when i do an npm install, npm wants me to install semantic ui.  I dont want/nor do I need semantic ui. Anyone know why npm is going through an interactive install for semantic ui?  I tried searching all over the google space and couldnt find an answer for this. Hopefully, someone can shed some light.

Comment: I don't think NPM is the one to blame. Semantic UI does that. See the video at http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Comment: @Darlesson is there a way to not allow semantic to go through its install then?

Comment: You might have "semantic-ui" in your package.json or another module under node_modules might have dependency on it. Look for "semantic-ui" in all files. If you have it package.json you just need to delete it.

Comment: @Darlesson I found the issue is with the `karma-dhtml-reporter`.  That library has semantic-ui as a dependency, which has an interactive install.  This wasnt a problem with npm 2.x, but with 3.x it goes into interactive install which causes install to fail on jenkins.  Removing this library fixed issue, so it looks like I will be going back to `karma-html-reporter`.  Thanks

Comment: I am also using Semantic with NPM and Jenkins. But I can let Semantic interactive installation to fail and run the build later using `semantic.json` to configure the build. Considering you don't have the control over this, I would recommend you to write a bug to `karma-dhtml-reporter` and see what they come up with even if you are not using them at this moment.